# Reading a plist on the mac

Tags: cocoa, macos, plist

I'm trying to set an image from reading a plist. I'm working on an app which uses the current desktop wallpaper and sets it as the windows background image. The files is located `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist`
How do I read a key from it? The specific keys i'm trying to read are;

```
NewImageFilePath
ImageFilePath
```

I have tried this code which is like reading a plist on the iPhone but it didnt work.

```
NSString *plistPath = @"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist";
NSDictionary *plistData = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath] retain];
NSString *item = [plistData objectForKey:@"NewImageFilePath"];

NSLog([NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", item]);
```

Once I can get the actual data located in the plists string my plan is to set it to an NSImageView or to the `[window setBackgroundColor:[color]];` method

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason you're retaining that dictionary? Also, you should rename that variable, since it contains a dictionary, not data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that some info on desktop images can be obtained via public APIS, starting from 10.6. Read `NSWorkspace` documentation, in particular [`-[NSWorkspace desktopImageOptionsForScreen:]`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000391-SW18) and such.

Answer (score 1):

According to the plist for my local user account, the following should do for you:

```
NSString *plistPath = @"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist";
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSString *item = [[[plistData objectForKey:@"Background"] objectForKey:@"default"] objectForKey:@"NewImageFilePath"];
```

An easier solution, and easier to read, is to use valueForKeyPath:

```
NSString *plistPath = @"~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.desktop.plist";
NSDictionary *plistData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSString *item = [plistData valueForKeyPath:@"Background.default.NewImageFilePath"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the plist look like this?

```
<dict>
    <key>NewImageFilePath</key>
    <string>...</string>
</dict>
```

If so, that code should work. But I'm guessing the keys aren't at the root of the first dict?

Answer (score 0):

I got everything working except for displaying the image now. Using

```
NSURL *address = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] desktopImageURLForScreen:[NSScreen mainScreen]];
```

I was able to get the address to the image. I now am trying to set the windows backgroundColor this image. Thanks for your help here.